# atomic write/read of a file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, save, load, atomic

My nodejs application is built around a "project file".

Several modules (by "module", I mean a simple javascript file of my project) of this application need to load, modify and save this file often, via streams (fs.createReadStream, fs.createWriteStream), and since those modules are executed independently from each other, with sometimes an origin from an websocket events (for instance), I need to make the save/load operations of the project file **atomic**.

It means the following scenario:

1. moduleA writes the project file
2. in the same time, and before moduleA has finished to write the file, moduleB wants to read it => ideally, it should wait for the write operation of moduleA (currently, it reads a partially written file and detect an error) before really read the file

Is nodejs able to do this natively or do I have to build a sort of atomic wrapper over my read/write stream system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is to my knowledge nothing built in. There are modules such as redis-lock though, that implement a lock mechanism.
If you run on a single non-clustered server you could probably cope with implementing a simple local lock though.

Answer (score 1):

This might give you an idea:

```js
var Fs = require("fs"),
    LOCK = require ("os").tmpdir () + '/foo-lock.';

function transLock(id, cb) {
  Fs.open(LOCK + id, "wx", function(err, fd) {
    if (err) {
      // someone else has created the file
      // or something went wrong
      cb(err);
    } else {
      Fs.close(fd, function(err) {
        // there should be no error here except weird stuff
        // like EINTR which must be ignored on Linux
        cb();
      });
    }
  });
}


function transUnlock(id) {
  Fs.unlink(LOCK + id, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      // something is wrong and nothing we can do except
      // perhaps log something or do some background cleanup
    }
  });
}

function main() {
  var id = "some-unique-name";

  transLock(id, function(err) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);
    else {
      // ... do your stuffs ...
      transUnlock(id);
    }
  });
}

main();
```

Comment: The main point here being you are always opening with write permission (even if the intention is only to read)  which is always granted atomically.